# ng-model for input element doesn't pass the value to a method call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this html template:

```
    <br>
    <input type="number"
           name="input"
           required
           class="form-control input-md"
           ng-model="totalPay"
           placeholder="Amount"
           ng-minlength="1"
           ng-maxlength="3"
           min="1"
           max="150">

<td><select ng-options="reason for reason in refundReasons" required ng-model="chosenReason">
    <option value="">Select refund reason</option>
</select></td>
<br>

<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="payDriver(userId, totalPay, chosenReason)">Pay driver</button>

</p>
```

for some reason I get `totalPay == undefined` no matter how I try to put it.

The other values `userId` and `chosenReason` are as expected.

my controller:

```
var opsToolControllers = angular.module('opsToolControllers');

opsToolControllers.controller('payoutCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'Util', 'User', 'Payout', function ($scope, $location, Util, User , Payout) {

    $scope.refundReasons = ["1 -- No show compensation", "2 -- Bonus not paid"];
    $scope.userId = null;
    $scope.totalPay = null;
```

this is the method in the controller i try to call:

```
$scope.payDriver = function (userId, total, chosenReason) {
    Payout.payDriver(userId, $scope.totalPay, chosenReason, successCallBack, errorCallBack())
};
```

the arg `total == undefined` and the body `$scope.totalPay == null`

Comment: can you add implementation of `payDriver` method?

Comment: You don't need to _pass_ the values to `payDriver()` as they are _already_ available in your $scope. Just call `payDriver()` and inside it, you have access to `$scope.totalPay`, `$scope.userId` and `$scope.chosenReason`.

Comment: @JeremyThille I have tried this as well. it's `null`.

Comment: So is it `null` or `undefined`? It's very different. `null` is defined.

Comment: I have this line in the controller ` $scope.totalPay = null;` so it stays `null` but not bind to the real value of the ui input

Comment: @JeremyThille I have edited my question

Comment: My guess it is creating a child scope. Try having a session object and add all your variables inside that. `$scope.session = {};` Then in all your `ng-model` use `session.userId` `session.refundReasons` `session.totalPay`

Comment: Honestly I don't know. There's no reason why `$scope.totalPay` should be null, because you bind it correctly in `<input ng-model="totalPay"/>`